# How to correctly perform SQL queries in background thread?

Tags: java, android, sql, multithreading, sqlite

I have a `ViewPager` that has one of the pages containing a `List` which is populated from the SQLite database. This `List` is filled by first grabbing a `Cursor` and then extracting all the various fields into objects that I then add to the `List`.

However I have also read that I should be performing SQL operations in another thread as to not make the entire app lag.

What is the correct way to do this? My SQLite class is implemented as a singleton so it suffices to call `MyDatabaseClass.getInstance(context)` when I need access.

Comment: AsyncTask? Just like an HTTP call if you've ever made one

Comment: @cricket_007 I have not made one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL background queries should be handled like any other background action. You can use e.g. `Thread`s or `AsyncTask`s to perform them.

---

### Thread example

```
public void performActionAsync(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           performAction();
        }
    }).start();
}

private void performAction(){
    //perform actions as normal
}
```

Comment: So within `performAction` I would do things like database reads and list-fills?

Comment: exactly. In fact this can just be the methods you already have.

Comment: But I would need to be careful not to run performActionAsync() and then something right after it that assumes the list is filled?

Comment: That is correct. You could either use a listener model or an eventbus to notify components when the asyncronous action completed.

Comment: How would I use a listener model to do that?

Comment: That is a separate question. Anyway, you can either register listeners on a per-call basis (those would be passed as argument in `performActionAsync`) or on a per-instance basis (you would need to add getters/setters to your `MyDatabaseClass`)